# Is the sum $f+g$ of two one-way-functions a one-way-function?

Tags: one-way-functions

Since there exists a bijection of sets from $\{0,1\}^*$ to $\mathbb{N_0}$, we might view one-way-functions as functions $f :\mathbb{N_0} \rightarrow \mathbb{N_0}$. My question is, suppose $f,g$ are one-way-functions, is then $(f+g)(n):=f(n)+g(n)$ a one-way-function or can one construct a counterexample? (The length of $n$ is $\text{ floor}(\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)})=$ the number of bits to represent $n$)

Comment on answer of @Bulat:
Suppose $f$ is an owf. If (?) there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{N_0}$ we have $f(x) \le x^k$. Then as @Bulat mentioned, construct $g(x) = x^k-f(x) \ge 0$. Then $g(x)$ is an owf as $f$ is, but $h(x) = g(x)+f(x) = x^k$ is not an owf. So the question is, if there exists such an $k$.
The argument would also work considering $k^x$ instead of $x^k$. But the same question remains? Why would such an $k$ exist?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dkaeae: Yes I realized that also.

Comment: Regarding your "comment": If the value of $f$ is polynomially bounded (i.e., $f(x) \le x^k$), then $f$ can be inverted by computing it on polynomially many values (e.g., $x^k + 1$ values) and using the pidgeonhole principle. So it seems that you want $k^x$ (actually $k^{|x|}$, I suppose?), in which case you might well have $k = 2$, which is a trivial bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

Given $f$ one-way, consider $g(x) = -f(x)$. $g$ is then also one-way, because inverting $g$ would imply inverting $f$.  In particular, supposing $g$ is not one-way, one can invert $f(x)$ simply by negating it and applying the inverter for $g$ (and the success probability is even equal).

In this setting, $h(x) = f(x) - f(x) = 0$ is not one-way as it can be.

Comment: But is $g$ a function which maps $\mathbb{N_0} $ to $\mathbb{N_0}$?

Comment: Well, then consider the negation modulo $N$, which is a large integer picked as a function of $n$ (e.g., $N = 2^n$). Then $h(x)$ will always be a predictable pattern (e.g., $10^\ast$).

Comment: The question asked specifically about bijective functions, also wikipedia page about OWF talks specifically about functions returning strings of zeroes

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is that you expect that for OWF each and any `f(x)` computation should be hard to reverse. But it seems incorrect, f.e. [modular squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#The_Rabin_function_(modular_squaring)) is easily reversible for `x=0`. EDIT: Wikipedia specifically says "Note that, by this definition, the function must be "hard to invert" in the average-case, rather than worst-case sense."

By using `g(x) = x - f(x)` you will have a pair of functions that are hard to revert, but their sum is identity function.

Comment: but how do you guarantee that $g(x)>=0$?

Comment: @orgesleka compute it modulo 2^N

Comment: what is N, the length of x in bits?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: I do not understand the argument with $2^N$. Maybe you can comment on that in your answer?

Comment: Can i ask you what is definition of your '+' operation? F.e. how it adds up two {1,1,1,...1} sequences? ;)

Comment: Represent those sequences in base $2$ and add the numbers. For example $\pi(\{1,\cdots,1\}) = 2^N-1$, where $N=|\{1,\cdots,1\}|$ is the length of the sequence.

Comment: I made some comment on your proof idea in my question. Maybe you can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider arbitrary one-way function `f(x)`. We want to construct easily reversible `h(x)` with the property `h(x) >= f(x) for any x`.

Let's encode in `h` result value x and then add enough to make sure that `h(x) >= f(x)`. We can do it f.e. in this way - use lower bits of result to RLE-encode `N = bit length of x value`, f.e. if it contains 3 bits then encoding will be `0111`, then encode `N` bits of x value itself, and finally, use higher bits to encode `f(x)` value shifted by `2*N+1` bits. Well, we can put in these bits arbitrary data as far as overall value is larger than the `f(x)`.

Comment: Thanks @Bulat for your insight to this question! (+1)